# Delaying events in a game loop with Android?

Tags: android, animation, surfaceview, game-loop

If you have a game loop thread in Android that draws to a surfaceview and you require a couple of seconds delay to perform animation, how do you go about doing this?

Comment: These kinds of question have been asked a lot - needing delays etc. Usually when you need a delay you should be using some sort of listener. That's android's solution to these kinds of issues.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone, and each tag has a specific use.  Combining the tags `[game]` and `[loop]` doesn't mean the same thing as the tag `[gameloop]`.  Please select your tags with care and *always* read the helpful descriptions that pop up while selecting them.